# Complex Integration involving Riemann zeta and Gamma functions

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration

Let $G(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi\iota}\int\limits_{(3/4)}\frac{\Gamma(1+t)^2}{(4\pi^2x)^t}\frac{dt}{t}$. Here, integration is over line such that real part is $\frac{3}{4}$. We can prove below result by using Stirling Approximation.
$G(x)<< \begin{cases} {1} & {x\leq 1}\\ {exp(-c\sqrt{x})}& {x>1}\end{cases}$ for some $c>0$.

My question is how to prove : $\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n}G(\frac{n^2}{x})=\frac{1}{2}log(x) +c_0 +\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{x})$.

As I have tried, LHS = $\frac{1}{2\pi\iota}\int\limits_{(3/4)}(\frac{x}{4\pi^2})^t\Gamma(1+t)^2\zeta(2t+1)\frac{dt}{t}$.

What can I do further?

Comment: Check your integrand again and the $\log(x)$ would come from the residue at $t= 0$

Comment: you can look at pg no 353 of the article... https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1112/S0024610799008637